# Using Event Bridge to run workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I want to schedule a workflow using Event Bridge.
I have a use case where I need to load data from S3 perform some analysis using a .py file (Sagemaker/EC2?) and load the results into RDS. And at the end shut everything down.
Does this sound logically for Event Bridge? Any suggestion on how to configure or better options?

Comment: depending on how long it takes to process the file from S3, you could have a S3 event notification that would trigger a lambda on file upload. The lambda can perform the analysis and write data to RDS (Lambda execution is limited to 15mins).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The analysis would take longer than 15 mins to run. Thats why I am looking at Event Bridge.

Comment: EventBridge is just a message bus. Yes EventBridge could trigger the workflow, but S3 also supports sending new S3 object notifications directly to other services like SQS and Lambda, so you may not need EventBridge. You first need to determine what the rest of the workflow looks like. Is it an AWS Glue job? An ECS task? A process running on an EC2 server? Once you determine that, there are plenty of ways (including EventBridge) to trigger one of those from an S3 new object event. The details of that depend on which exact service you use to do the data processing.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB. The goal is for the trigger to be new data ingested into S3. And SM Notebook or EC2 instance would run the .py file and output the results into RDS. And shut down when finished. If the S3 Event Notification can trigger that workflow, that sounds efficient to me. How would I go about it?

Comment: "How would I go about it?" I don't know, you still haven't specified specifically what you want to do. Are you using SageMaker, or EC2? You are focusing on what is probably the easiest part of the problem, while being unspecific about the part that is probably 99% of the actual problem. I suggest building _something_ in AWS that you can trigger manually to process a file and load it into RDS. Once you have done that, post a question here about the details of what you built, and ask how to trigger it automatically.

Comment: The process is currently ran manually in a Sagemaker notebook. It pulls the data from s3, does some cleaning and loads that data into RDS postgresql. The cleaning process does take longer than 15 mins, that's what sent me on a search for another alternative other than Lambda. @MarkB

Comment: Then it seems like your question should be restated as "how do I trigger a sagemaker notebook when a file is uploaded to S3".

Comment: If your question is on triggering a SageMaker notebook, look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/create-notebook-auto-run.html. You can run the ipynb file as a standalone job. You can also look at processing jobs if your script can be run using scikit-learn. These jobs can be invoked from Lambda or using SageMaker pipelines.